# YouTube shows "Missing Plug-in" in window after installing Flash

Tags: flash, chromium, youtube

After installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit, I have installed Ubuntu Restricted Extras, configured Medibuntu, and installed Synaptic Package Manager. I tried to install Adobe Flash Player by installing Chromium. I also files to play encrypted DVDs. I haven't been able to locate the `flashplayer` file in the `/usr/lib` folders, which I assume should be there. I don't know if this is why I can't see videos at YouTube.  Not sure where else to look.

Comment: Chromium doesn't come with flash Google Chrome does. Have you installed flash from the software centre?

Answer (score 2):

The file should be located in `/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/`.  For my Flash problem, the only solution that worked was downgrading.  I wrote a script as I became tired of downgrading.  Here is the code below:

```
wget http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_11.1.102.63_archive.zip
unzip fp_11.1.102.63_archive.zip tar -xzvf
fp_11.1.102.63_archive/11_1r102_63_32bit/flashplayer11_1r102_63_linux.i386.tar.gz
-C fp_11.1.102.63_archive/ sudo cp -f fp_11.1.102.63_archive/libflashplayer.so
/usr/lib/flashplugin-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

Install the `flashplugin-installer` package to install Flash.

To play encrypted DVDs you need `libdvdcss2` from the Medibuntu repository; note that this is illegal in some countries.

To install both from the terminal (after adding [Medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org/repository.php)):

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer libdvdcss2
```

Comment: I have done all that mentioned above.  Still a no-go.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Install Flash]

As I explained in my comment **Google** chrome is the only browser with flash pre-installed  for everything else there is the adobe flash plug-in just search for it in the software centre

Hope this helps

Comment: Tried the above and did not work.  I already have that version mentioned above installed.  I am trying to find out in what folders this installation is located.  I thought it would be in /usr/lib, but couldn't find flash-player there.

Comment: What does http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ say when you visit it?

Answer (score 0):

Just as a check, have you tried restarting your browser after installing Flash? Sometimes Flash won't start working until you do so. You could try restarting Ubuntu as well and see if that has any effect.